# How can I change default css of "datatable" print button?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

How can I change the css of print and excel buttons in datatable plugin.

```
                    $('#order_table').DataTable({
                        dom: 'Brtip',
                        buttons: [
                             'print','excel'
                        ]
                    });
                });
```

Comment: It happens in two separate set of code. First you initialize the Datatables and then you use the table tools plugin of the datatables to get the button styles and functions defined

Comment: I have done similar thing. Let me know if you want me to help you with my solution.

Comment: Please  share the code or the hints to solution

Answer (score 3):

Each button have a unique base class `.buttons-print`, `.buttons-excel`, `.buttons-copy` etc. So you can style the buttons directly with CSS

```css
.buttons-print {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.buttons-excel {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/mg28pxe2/**

---

To replace `.btn-default` with `.btn-primary` :

```
$('.buttons-excel, .buttons-print').each(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary')
})
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/48rcjrw3/**

Comment: I am using with Bootstrap. I have to change the the default css class to "btn-primary"..

Comment: @AbdulRazak, so you want to change the default injected classes, not the CSS itself? See update.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var orderDataTable =  $('#order_table').DataTable({
                        dom: 'Brtip',
                        buttons: [
                             'print','excel'
                        ]
                    });



     var tableTools_obj = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(orderDataTable , {
                    "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "aButtons": [                           
                            {
                                "sExtends": "xls",
                                "sTitle": "OrdersReport",
                                "sToolTip": "Export to Excel",
                                "sButtonClass": "btn btn-transparent btn-primary btn-toolbar", // Here you can give all the classes realated to button with custom styles.
                                "sButtonText": "<i title='Export To Excel' class='ace-icon fa fa-file-excel-o white icon-tooltip'></i>", //overriding the default icon of Datatables, Here I am using Fontawsome icons
                               // "mColumns": GetExportableColumnsIndexes(); //this is to filter out hidden or unwanted columns form being exported.
                              // Usually it requires array on indexes, I prefer to call a function with some logic handling and returning the  required indexes.
                            }
                        ]
                    });
```

For this you must add the TableTools plugin of datatables. http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js

Let me know if this was helpful.